# How to run an executable file on OS X

Tags: terminal, executable

I follow [this](http://logz.io/blog/docker-stats-monitoring-dockbeat/) blog to use Dockbeat and at a certain moment it says that I need to download a file and to make it executable then to run it so I did:

```
wget https://github.com/Ingensi/dockbeat/releases/download/v1.0.0/dockbeat-v1.0.0-x86_64
chmod +x dockbeat-v1.0.0-x86_64
./dockbeat-v1.0.0-x86_64 -c dockbeat-1.0.0/dockbeat.yml -v -e
```

As the blog describe but I have this error:

```
-bash: ./dockbeat-v1.0.0-x86_64: cannot execute binary file
```

Although when I do  `ls -l dockbeat-v1.0.0-x86_64`
I got:

```
-rwxr-xr-x  1 dav_NG  staff  13412840 12 sep 14:17 dockbeat-v1.0.0-x86_64
```

So my question is why can't I run it ? (I checked and my OS X support 64bits)

Answer (score 1):

I ran into your question when I was investigating why I couldn't run dockbeat on my own Mac OS X so I post here what worked for me.

In fact, the file `dockbeat-v1.0.0-x86_64` you downloaded is a Linux executable, you can verify by typing the `file dockbeat-v1.0.0-x86_64` command.

In order to run dockbeat on Mac OS X, you first have to compile the sources to generate a Mac executable (see the [dockbeat's Github documentation](https://github.com/Ingensi/dockbeat#build-dockbeat)).

Here are the steps that I followed:

1. Install Golang and Glide on your Mac OS X.
2. Navigate to `${GOPATH}/github.com/ingensi` and create missing directories. For instance, in my case, I installed go with homebrew so the complete path I ended up with was `/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.8.1/libexec/src/github.com/ingensi`
3. In the `ingensi` directory, run `git clone https://github.com/Ingensi/dockbeat.git`
4. Enter in the cloned directory by typing `cd dockbeat`. You should now be in the `${GOPATH}/github.com/ingensi/dockbeat` directory.
5. Run the `make`command. This will generate a Mac OS X `dockbeat` executable.
6. Configure dockbeat by editing the file `etc/dockbeat.yml`
7. Run normally with the command `./dockbeat -c etc/dockbeat.yml`

Hope this helps :-)